# Regex parse Youtube url with CSV Video ID

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to grab YouTube video id which is in comma separated format.

url : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClcKC_U_7fM,ujmoYyEyDP8,cwRFjWdxeRQ,Z4BKV121mP4,T241s7O7-Io

My expected output :

```
ClcKC_U_7fM, ujmoYyEyDP8, cwRFjWdxeRQ, Z4BKV121mP4, T241s7O7-Io
```

I tried following

```
Regex regexPattern = new Regex(@"""[^""\r\n]*""|'[^'\r\n]*'|[^,\r\n]*");
    Match matchResults = regexPattern.Match(url);
    while (matchResults.Success) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(matchResults.Value);
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    }
```

Output

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClcKC_U_7fM

ujmoYyEyDP8

cwRFjWdxeRQ

Z4BKV121mP4

T241s7O7-Io
```

I tried other method

```
 var regex = new Regex(@"(?:.+?)?(?:\\/v\\/|watch\\/|\\?v=|\\&v=|youtu\\.be\\/|\\/v=|^youtu\\.be\\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})+");
            foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(url))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(match);
                foreach (var groupdata in match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Where(groupdata => !groupdata.ToString().StartsWith("http://") && !groupdata.ToString().StartsWith("https://") && !groupdata.ToString().StartsWith("youtu") && !groupdata.ToString().StartsWith("www.")))
                {
                    groupdata.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(groupdata.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Output

```
ClcKC_U_7fM
```

Any idea in getting following result ?

```
ClcKC_U_7fM, ujmoYyEyDP8, cwRFjWdxeRQ, Z4BKV121mP4, T241s7O7-Io
```

> Update

I forgot to mention various url pattern

```
1) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClcKC_U_7fM,ujmoYyEyDP8,cwRFjWdxeRQ,Z4BKV121mP4,T241s7O7-Io

2) http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ClcKC_U_7fM,ujmoYyEyDP8,cwRFjWdxeRQ,Z4BKV121mP4,T241s7O7-Io

3) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClcKC_U_7fM,ujmoYyEyDP8,cwRFjWdxeRQ,Z4BKV121mP4,T241s7O7-Io&feature=related
```

Thanks

Comment: split the url usnig "string[] words = url.Split('=');" then use the second part of the string with your code

Comment: why do you need regex for this?...you can simply do it with the string **Split()** method.

Comment: A regex solution would be `(?<=[=,])[^,]*`.

Comment: oops! Sorry to mention various url pattern. I have update my question.

Comment: @MikMark I have updated my answer for your updated question.

Comment: In your 3rd example, the first value changes from "ClcKC_U_7fM" to "i-ClcKC_U_7fM".  Is this intentional?  Are you looking for a regex that will also drop the "i-"?

Comment: sorry it's my mistake. It's "ClcKC_U_7fM", not i-ClcKC_U_7fM. I just update it. Anyways thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the original code posted by the OP, substitute the following for the regular expression `(?<=(v=)|,)[^(,|&)]*`

```
string url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClcKC_U_7fM,ujmoYyEyDP8,cwRFjWdxeRQ,Z4BKV121mP4,T241s7O7-Io";
Regex regexPattern = new Regex("(?<=(v=)|,)[^(,|&)]*");
Match matchResults = regexPattern.Match(url);
while (matchResults.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(matchResults.Value);
    matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
}
```

Output:

```
ClcKC_U_7fM
ujmoYyEyDP8
cwRFjWdxeRQ
Z4BKV121mP4
T241s7O7-Io
```

Comment: Just noticed comment made by @Rawing about 15 minutes before I posted this.  Although I didn't see it prior to my post, he/she deserves credit for the answer, both due to time of submission and simplicity (i.e. no capture groups).

Comment: The OP has updated his question which presents different patterns of url

Comment: @mjb - Answer updated.  Now looks for `v=` instead of just `=`

Comment: @ClayVerValen for the 3rd URL, your code splits the string perfectly but the result has an extra `&feature=related` in `T241s7O7-Io&feature=related`.

Comment: @Rakitić - Good catch.  I've updated the regular expression to account for ampersands after the comma separated values.

Comment: @ClayVerValen yup, working fine :) [Demo Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/veF2Rs)

Answer (score 1):

```
string url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ClcKC_U_7fM,ujmoYyEyDP8,cwRFjWdxeRQ,Z4BKV121mP4,T241s7O7-Io";

string[] s1 = url.Split('?');
string[] queries = s1[1].Split('&');

foreach (string query in queries)
{
    if (query.ToLower().StartsWith("v="))
    {
        string[] s2 = query.Split('=');
        string[] s3 = s2[1].Split(',');

        foreach (string s in s3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier if you first split your url at the `=` sign and then use a simple string split.

Comment: oops! sorry to mention twist in url. sometime i get url like http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ClcKC_U_7fM,ujmoYyEyDP8,cwRFjWdxeRQ,Z4BKV121mP4,T241s7O7-Io

Comment: in which case, instead of splitting at `=`, you would split at `v=`